# Difference between rlm() and lm_robust

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, robust

Due to outliers, I would like to use a robust regression method instead of lm().

I can't decide whether to use lm_robust (estimatr package) or rlm (MASS package).
Are there mathematical differences between the functions?
Which one would you recommend?

Comment: These are quite different, `MASS::rlm` implements [M-estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator) whereas `estimatr::lm_robust` returns [sandwich variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroskedasticity-consistent_standard_errors). It really depends on what you want to have 'robust'.

Comment: Thank you! I mainly have the problem with the outliers and that the residuals are not normally distributed...

Comment: The lmrob() function from the robustbase package also seems to be a possible option, in which case should I use that one?

Comment: You could use an M-estimator like `MASS::rlm` or `robustbase::lmrob`, and then use e.g. the `sandwich` package to obtain sandwich (co)variance. Just the sandwich variance won't help as much for outliers (although their apparent presence makes linear regression possibly questionable in the first place).

Comment: This Q. feels like it's on the boundary between Stack Overflow and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com): "which procedure should I use?" is for CV, and "how do I implement it?" is for here.  @PBulls, would you like to write up an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Robust' is one of those terms like 'exact' or 'weighted' in statistics; they are applied equally to what may turn out to be very different approaches. As the [Wikipedia article for robust regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression#Applications) explains there are broadly at least two issues that can cause regular linear regression to go awry:

- outliers, or highly influential observations that due to their location have a much larger impact on parameter estimates than other observations if they are in- or excluded from the fit.
- lack of homoscedasticity or homogeneity of variance (all errors being identically and independently distributed, a key assumption in many statistical models).

Each of these has their own remedies, and the packages you mention implement some of those: `MASS::rlm` and `robustbase::lmrob` fit so-called [M-estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator), which can have higher breakdown points (tolerance for outliers) than regular maximum likelihood estimators. `estimatr::lm_robust` rather fits a [heteroscedasticity-consistent variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroskedasticity-consistent_standard_errors), more broadly a sandwich (co)variance estimator, which relaxes the homoscedasticity assumption.

From your comments it seems like your data might primarily be affected by outliers, so `MASS::rlm` or `robustbase::lmrob` would then be the better options to try first. What's more, using for example the [`sandwich`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sandwich) package you can obtain a sandwich covariance estimate for many different kinds of models fit in R, so a combination might get you the best of both.

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know if its possible to combine a robust regression method like  MASS::rlm or robustbase::lmrob with rms::rcs to use restricted cubic splines?

Comment: @Vivien yes, for example `MASS::rlm(hp ~ rms::rcs(mpg), data=mtcars)` will give you a spline effect. It may not handle the effect naming etc. as nicely as `rms` itself but the fit should work, just as if you were to manually provide the basis functions yourself.